# Subtraction according to some parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've the following table
[image]

each code has both + and - signs or either + or - sign. What I want to do is to subtract amount for each code. The problem is to do so if there is no both + and - signs. For instance, entry with code 45 has only '-' sign, it means that '+' sign here is 0, so we have to do 0-500=-500. I've to come up with the following table. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a `CASE` statement, like this:

```
SELECT CODE, SUM (CASE Sign WHEN '-' THEN -Amount ELSE Amount END) as Total
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Code
```